# Using Array for keeping track of rows and columns

Tags: java

I am loading my level for a game  through xml.

I have a loop that test the "name" and adds the sprite accordingly.

I have a map that has tiles that are 80by80 width and height. The maps rows and columns are 6x10.

I am trying to find a way to keep track of which row and column the level loader is on while it is loading the tiles, because i want to do specific things with the coordinates.

I have thought of using a 2d array for this but i am not sure how i would go about doing this in this situation.

Could anyone help me out with this?

EDIT:

Here is what i have tried.

Creating a row and column array

```
 int row[] = new int[6];
 int col[] = new int[10];
```

Now here is where i am stuck, im not sure how i can tell the code when to switch and use a different row. For example..

```
if (name.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_unwalkable)) {
    tile = new Tile(x, y, this.tUnwalkable_tile,
            activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    tileList.add(tile);
    tile.setTag(1);

    /*
     * Body groundBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld,
     * tile, BodyType.StaticBody, wallFixtureDef);
     */
    gameScene.getChildByIndex(SECOND_LAYER).attachChild(tile);
    Log.e("Tile", "Unwalkable_Tile");
    return;
} else if (name.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_Blue_Tile)) {
    tile = new Tile(x, y, this.blue,
            activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    tile.setTag(0);
    this.tileList.add(tile);
    gameScene.getChildByIndex(SECOND_LAYER).attachChild(tile);
    return;

} else if (name.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_Red_Tile)) {
    tile = new Tile(x, y, this.red, activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    tileList.add(tile);
    tile.setTag(0);
    gameScene.getChildByIndex(SECOND_LAYER).attachChild(tile);
    return;
} else if (name.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_Pink_Tile)) {
    tile = new Tile(x, y, this.pink,
            activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    tileList.add(tile);
    tile.setTag(0);
    gameScene.getChildByIndex(SECOND_LAYER).attachChild(tile);
    return;
} else if (name.equals(TAG_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE_Yello_Tile)) {
    tile = new Tile(x, y, this.yellow,
            activity.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    tileList.add(tile);
    tile.setTag(0);
    gameScene.getChildByIndex(SECOND_LAYER).attachChild(tile);
    return;

    }
```

How do i tell it to stay row[1] until the col[10] is reached?

Then switch to row[2] and stay there until col[10] is reached again?

Comment: Is there any reason the level loader itself can't keep track of which row and column it is loading? Surely it must know to where it is loading the data.

Comment: Yes i created the level loader it reads an xml file. Ill post the loader code if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a design standpoint, your level loader should just be loading the level.  Whatever magical transform you want to do on top of that can and most likely should be handled separately.

So just have your level loader create a 2d array of... whatever it's reading.  Are you reading a flat set of tile elements?  Then count the number of elements read.  At any given point, your offset is:

```
 x = count % 10;
 y = count / 6;
```

If you have each row in an encapsulating element, count the rows, and the columns.  Same idea.

Now you've got a 2d array (or some object encapsulating it).  And you can do whatever transformations you want on it.   If you want this in terms of screen space, instead multiply each count by 80.

Edit: from the edit above, it looks like you're declaring separate row and column arrays, which you probably don't want to do.  It would more logically be something like:

```
int[][] tiles = new int[6][];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  tiles[i] = new int[10];  
}
```

Then, in your loader, define a counter somewhere (once).

```
int counter = 0;
```

You'll switch rows when:

```
counter > 0 && (counter++) % 10 == 0
```

But with a 2d array, you can really just think of it as having coordinates, as I mentioned above:

```
 x = counter % 10;
 y = counter / 6;
```

And in the end, you have one tiles[][] variable that holds all the tile data.  So you can say:

```
tiles[x][y] = <whatever data you need to store>
```

And remember to increment the counter, once you're done.

Comment: I added some code of what i have tried above. Also could you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: You don't want two separate arrays... you want one array in two dimensions.

Comment: Right like coords[][]. But could you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: I've added a bit above.  But you don't actually use row or col anywhere, so it's unclear what you mean to actually use them for.